# Bring featured articles to the front of the articles retrieved by ArticlesModel

Tags: articles, model

How can I bring the featured articles to the front of the articles array retrieved by the ArticlesModel?

I know I can change the ordering via this line:

```
$model->setState('list.ordering', $ordering);
```

But that is for example on the publish up or down string. But how can I bring the featured articles to the front?

Is that possible with the model or do I just need to loop through the array, and manually bring these items to the front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order by featured column and use descending direction:

```
$model->setState('list.ordering', 'a.featured');
$model->setState('list.direction', 'DESC');
```

Comment: Does this also order the rest of the articles on the published date?

Comment: No. You can use `a.featured DESC, a.publish_up DESC` for ordering and an empty string for direction (or `a.featured DESC, a.publish_up` and `DESC`) to order by featured state and published date. But I wouldn't trust this too much, it could break at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You could use filter.featured=1 to select just the filtered articles and then select the non featured articles and combine the arrays.